# How to dynamicaly stretch rows section in table with fixed header

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have page with header, footer and single table with fixed header. See code in sandbox (open results view in new window)

[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-k7xqp)

I want to stretch rows section, that have own scrollbar, to avoid page vertical scroller appearance.

Answer (score -1):

Caused by document margin (made a reset for that) plus u used `100vh` on `Demo` causing the document margin to overflow.

`reset.css`

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

try this https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-xmknq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark